# Not sure on how to use a setter, Getter works fine

Tags: vb.net, getter-setter

After a button press I'm trying to send the value in my listbox to the setter in the same form.

```
Dim strSponsorName As String = "Initial Value"
Private Sub btnAddSponsor_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddSponsor.Click
    SponsorName() = "Second Value"

    ' Create new instance of adding a sponsor
    frmAddSponsor.ShowDialog()
    ' reload EventGolferSponsor form
    frmEventGolferSponsors_Load(sender, e)
End Sub

Public Property SponsorName() As String
    Get
        Return strSponsorName
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        strSponsorName = value
    End Set
End Property
```

When calling the Get, it still has the value of "Initial Value".
Not use how to use the Set to change the value to "Second Value"?

Comment: Your get/set is fine, but you should be setting the value like `SponsorName = "Second Value"` not `SponsorName() = "Second Value"`

Comment: `SponsorName = "NewValue"` should do it, the `()` are unnesseceareary- that word, you get it!

Comment: The code that is shown is fine.  As @soohoonigan said, you should leave off the () on the property, but VS2017 doesn't care, and didn't impact behavior when I tossed it into a quick console app. Maybe show the place you're reading it from?

Comment: If I remove the _frmAddSponsor.ShowDialog()_ and the _frmEventGolferSponsors_Load_ then I get the expected value in the property. So something happens in these two. Probably you reset the property to its initial value

Comment: The getter i have is lblSponsorName.Text = frmEventGolferSponsors.SponsorName    But the label text reads "Initial Value" not "Second Value"